# combine several exposed filters into one exposed (search) form?

Tags: views

Is there an easy way to combine two or more exposed filters into one shared exposed form? So that I don't have to have several search fields for each and every field that I want to filter.

Is this possible? Any modules that does this? I am using the Better Exposed Filters module.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

Views 3 provides solution for your question from the box. 
It's `Global: Combine fields` filter.

1. Add fields.
2. Add `Global: Combine fields filter` to filter criteria.
3. Check fields you want to combine in filter's settings.

If you use Display suite or teasers mode - force using fields in the View settings (under Format -> Settings).

Comment: The "force using field" saved me a lot of time. Thanks! This option is located  under Format -> Settings

Answer (score 2):

We accomplished this using [Views filters populate](http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate)

> This is an utility module. Its sole purpose is to fill in one blank that seems not easy to be done using normal views, which is to use one exposed string filter to search on multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

The search module packaged with core allows you to add a filter called "Search" which queries a users input against the search index. I have found this to be effective in similar situations.