# How to use single search box (autocomplete) for users and content?

Tags: 7, views

How can I use single search box with autocomplete for all the users on site and all the content of particular content type like blogs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create two views this can be achieved by modifying the query if you are using views. You can easily alter the query, if you are using the custom form then you can use Form API with autocomplete and in autocomplete callback you can do whatever you want. I have solved this using the autocomplete and its callback using FAPI

Comment: Thank you, I also did this using autocomplete and its callback using FAPI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exposed filters you can use the [Better Exposed Filters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), this allows you to combine serveral exposed filters into one filter.

How this works is described here: [combine several exposed filters into one exposed (search) form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40629/combine-several-exposed-filters-into-one-exposed-search-form)

Comment: I can create 2 views , first one for content (blog) and second for all users. Can I create a single exposed filter for both blog title and user name with autocomplete using Better exposed filter ?